# Limit number of image uploads JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to limit the number of image uploads so that the user can include a maximum of 4 images. It does not seem to work just adding a simple `if (files.length > 4)` statement. I want to prevent user from uploading more than allowed number of files.
How is it possible to achieve this and what would be the logic of such solution using JavaScript?

```js
    let inputFile = document.getElementById("addImg1");
    let rowOfPhotos = document.getElementById("row-of-product-photos");

    inputFile.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
      let files = e.target.files;
      let output = rowOfPhotos;

      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        let file = files[i];

        if (file) {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
            console.log(this);

            let imageFile = e.target;

            let divDocument = document.createElement("div");
            let divDocumentClose = document.createElement("div");
            let image = document.createElement("img");

            divDocument.setAttribute("class", "id-document");
            divDocumentClose.setAttribute("class", "id-document-close");

            image.setAttribute("class", "image-preview");
            image.setAttribute("style", "width: inherit; height: inherit; border-radius: 20px;");
            image.setAttribute("src", imageFile.result);

            divDocument.appendChild(divDocumentClose);
            divDocument.appendChild(image);
            rowOfPhotos.appendChild(divDocument);
          });

          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
          image.style.display = null;
        }
      }
    });
    document.querySelectorAll(".id-document-close").forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener("click", e => {
        this.parentElement.style.display = "none";
      });
    });
```

```css
.id-document{
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: url(webimage/mario.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 3%;
}

.id-document-close{
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -8px;
  top: -6px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: url(icons/close-white.svg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 11px;
  background-color: #282b2e;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
        <div class="verification-main-input-div">
          <p class="verification-main-text">Add a photo with your item (optional)</p>
          <div id="row-of-product-photos" class="row-of-id-photos">
            <div class="two1" id="addImgLabel1">
              <label for="addImg1" class="input-label inputLabelCss">
                <div class="photosvg">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                    stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                    class="feather feather-camera camera-icon">
                    <path d="M23 19a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V8a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4l2-3h6l2 3h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2z"></path>
                    <circle cx="12" cy="13" r="4"></circle>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </label> <!-- ngIf: images.length<maxImagesForProduct -->
              <input id="addImg1" type="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" style="display:none" multiple="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You can use `let files = [...e.target.files.slice(0, 4)]` to take only 4 files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the number of uploaded files in a variable and check if the number of newly uploaded files combined with the previous uploaded ones exceeds the maximum. Increment the variable each time more files are successfully added and decrease it by one each time an image is closed.

```
let numOfFiles = 0;
inputFile.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
      let files = e.target.files;
      let output = rowOfPhotos;
      if(numOfFiles + files.length > 4){
        alert("You can only upload at most 4 files!");
        return;
      }
      numOfFiles += files.length;
      //...
      divDocumentClose.addEventListener("click", e => {
              divDocument.style.display = "none";
              numOfFiles--;
      });
      //...
});
```

Demo:

```js
    let inputFile = document.getElementById("addImg1");
    let rowOfPhotos = document.getElementById("row-of-product-photos");
        let numOfFiles = 0;
    inputFile.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
      let files = e.target.files;
      let output = rowOfPhotos;
            if(numOfFiles + files.length > 4){
        alert("You can only upload at most 4 files!");
        return;
      }
      numOfFiles += files.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        let file = files[i];

        if (file) {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.addEventListener("load", function (e) {

            let imageFile = e.target;

            let divDocument = document.createElement("div");
            let divDocumentClose = document.createElement("div");
            let image = document.createElement("img");

            divDocument.setAttribute("class", "id-document");
            divDocumentClose.setAttribute("class", "id-document-close");

            image.setAttribute("class", "image-preview");
            image.setAttribute("style", "width: inherit; height: inherit; border-radius: 20px;");
            image.setAttribute("src", imageFile.result);

            divDocument.appendChild(divDocumentClose);
            divDocument.appendChild(image);
            divDocumentClose.addEventListener("click", e => {
              divDocument.style.display = "none";
              numOfFiles--;
            });
            rowOfPhotos.appendChild(divDocument);
          });

          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
          image.style.display = null;
        }
      }
    });
```

```css
.id-document{
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: url(webimage/mario.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 3%;
}

.id-document-close{
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -8px;
  top: -6px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: url(icons/close-white.svg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 11px;
  background-color: #282b2e;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
        <div class="verification-main-input-div">
          <p class="verification-main-text">Add a photo with your item (optional)</p>
          <div id="row-of-product-photos" class="row-of-id-photos">
            <div class="two1" id="addImgLabel1">
              <label for="addImg1" class="input-label inputLabelCss">
                <div class="photosvg">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                    stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                    class="feather feather-camera camera-icon">
                    <path d="M23 19a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V8a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4l2-3h6l2 3h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2z"></path>
                    <circle cx="12" cy="13" r="4"></circle>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </label> <!-- ngIf: images.length<maxImagesForProduct -->
              <input id="addImg1" type="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" style="display:none" multiple="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: is it possible to block new files from displaying after the 4th one? If we select more than 4 at once, the alert is triggered, but if we select one by one, they just keep appearing even outside their parent ```row``` div.

Comment: @user12051965 I've updated my answer. Does that work for you?

Comment: @user12051965 No problem.